# WinSCP/CuteFTP - Download files owned by another user

Tags: sudo, winscp, ownership

I have a "sudo user" account created on my server.

When using PuTTY, `sudo` "operation" allows me to do any operation without any problems; However I have a 37M file I need to check and I need to download it to my local machine; the problem is that WinSCP/CuteFTP is unable to download a file owned by another user. Is there a way to download that file without changing the owner?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/647919/how-to-change-user-in-winscp or http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect via Putty switch to user by using your sudo privilege. Then copy file under /tmp folder. After that you would be able to download that file via winscp/cuteFTP.